# iOS AFNetworking & Json Data

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I have a dictionary of son values but i can't seem to retrieve more than one value.  I'm new to this and am sure I'm just overlooking something or going at it entirely wrong.

This is the json data i receive in console:

```
`2015-03-10 16:41:46.693 Json[8118:629760] https://outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com/igq8ev0-9780785265740.jpg
2015-03-10 16:41:46.694 Json[8118:629760] {
    attributes =     {
        "Author(s)" = "John Eldredge";
        Format = Paperback;
        "ISBN-10" = 0785265740;
        "Page Count" = 288;
        "Publication Date" = "April 2002";
        Publisher = "Nelson, Thomas, Inc.";
    };
    barcode = 9780785265740;
    images =     (
        "https://outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com/igq8ev0-9780785265740.jpg"
    );
    name = "Wild at Heart Field Manual: A Personal Guide to Discover the Secret of Your Masculine Soul";
    "outpan_url" = "http://www.outpan.com/view_product.php?barcode=9780785265740";
    videos =     (
    );
}
```

this is the code where is am trying to retrieve the data - i can get the response if i ask for only one thing - but, when i try to get multiple values it sigbrt
I an trying to get the images url, the name, and the barcode.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
static NSString * const BaseURLString =     @"http://www.outpan.com/api/get-product.php?barcode=9780785265740&apikey=bbb053368784fed4f89d37f5fbabcf4";
```

...

```
- (IBAction)showJson:(id)sender {



// 1
NSString *string = BaseURLString;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// 2
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    // 3
   NSDictionary *dic  = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
     NSArray *imagesUrl = [dic objectForKey:@"images"];
    NSString *imagesUrlString = [imagesUrl objectAtIndex:0];
      NSLog(@"%@", imagesUrlString);
   NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

//this crashes - 
 //    NSArray *bookName = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
  //  NSString *bookNameString = [bookName objectAtIndex:0];
  //    NSLog(@"%@", bookNameString);
  // NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

}



failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    // 4
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]    initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                        message:    [error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}];

// 5
[operation start];


}
@end
```

Comment: So, where is the exception message and exception stack trace??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that is running for me.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://www.outpan.com/api/get-product.php?barcode=9780785265740&apikey=2bbb053368784fed4f89d37f5fbabcf4" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    NSDictionary *aDict = (NSDictionary*)responseObject;
    NSLog(@" name %@",[aDict objectForKey:@"name"]);
    NSLog(@" images %@",[aDict objectForKey:@"images"]);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

And this is the console that I get.

```
2015-03-11 04:39:43.038 del[49323:3297516]  name Wild at Heart Field Manual: A Personal Guide to Discover the Secret of Your Masculine Soul
2015-03-11 04:39:43.038 del[49323:3297516]  images (
    "https://outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com/igq8ev0-9780785265740.jpg"
)
```

Comment: thanks!  I had the info all along i just didn't know how to access it.

Comment: @ClayD Glad to be of help. Happy coding. :D